# what is the output coordinate system when I use Near3D tool in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I added a 3D rectangular surface (rectangle formed by 3D points) and a 3D point as two different shapefiles and then I tried to use Near3D tool. Then it gives an error "Datum conflict between input and output". I checked my coordinate systems and all the three (Scene, point and polygon) are in same geographic coordinate system which is "WGS_1984". What am I missing?

Comment: What is your data frame coordinate system? And are you sure it is an error? Seems to be a warning - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp0000001v000632. Perhaps you could insert a screenshot of the dialog box or the whole GP tool Messages window.

Comment: thanx! actually the problem was with GCS it seems...i projected the dataframe and also shapefiles to UTM coordinate system and then it worked very well...though im not sure of the accuracy of the result!